# I lost my keystore before publishing my app in Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, android-keystore

I'm finishing my app and It's still not published in Google Play. I already `Generated Signed APKs` and a `keystore.jks` for tests. But I lost the `keystore`. I made a new one and added it inside my firebase (because I use google auth).

Should I add the `debug.keystore` to firebase? And will there be any problems to release my app after creating a new keystore.jks?

Comment: if your app still not published, then no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your app isn't published, you don't need to worry.  You can publish it using the new key.

Clean your project and rebuild it before you set the new key.  Android Studio caches the previous path of the key so it may throw an error if you don't clean and rebuild.